# Why does Flutter install old versions of the Android SDK?

Tags: android, flutter

I thought it would be a good idea to update my Flutter app to use Android 14 (API 34) and remove old versions of the Android SDK from my dev machine.  But running the app reinstalls the old SDK versions I just removed.

I updated my build.gradle so that targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion are both set to 34 (minSdkVersion still at 23).  I then proceeded to remove the "old" Android SDKs in Android Studio.  But when I run the Flutter app I notice that it reinstalls these old SDKs (30, 31, 32, & 33).  Why?  Do I have something misconfigured somewhere?  Is it dependencies in my Flutter project, my Android project?  Dependencies in Flutter itself?  What causes this?

Comment: can you post your app/build.gradle (after removing personal/project related metadata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41462#issuecomment-582077176) is the answer from one of the Google employees. It looks like this is simply required by some transitive dependencies